# Dúvidas sobre instalação e uso do PHP

Tags: php

Boa noite

Como posso fazer para funcionar a linguagem `PHP`, e qual versão escolher?

S.O Windowns 10, para uso local.

Comment: Procura o xampp....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que possa utilizar o PHP em sua maquina localmente, você deverá instalar um ambiente que faz o papel de servidor do seu projeto. Pacotes como WAMP ou XAMPP são os mais comuns de serem utilizados para este cenário.

Eu particularmente utilizo e gosto mais do XAMPP mas o WAMP também é muito bom.
Neles você terá todas as ferramentas que precisará inicialmente para a programação utilizando a linguagem PHP.

No entanto, recomendo que faça uma pesquisa sobre como criar seus projetos com estas ferramentas. Algumas configurações básicas podem ser necessárias para que consiga desfrutar de uma perfeita utilização.

Aqui neste link [Como utilizar o XAMPP para criação de um servidor local](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O90gjjJfO-4), você encontra um exemplo de tutorial básico de utilização do XAMPP.

Sobre a versão acredito que vá depender mais da sua necessidade. Caso não tenha nenhum motivo específico, busque utilizar a versão mais recente da tecnologia que vá usar.